# how to disable varnish X Forwarded For header

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, varnish

i am using nginx <=> varnish <=> apache

i am passing client IP to varnish via nginx **proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;**

but varnish also adding X-Forwarded-For as 127.0.0.1 so apache showing 2 IPs comma based.

i need IP send by nginx only i want to disable varnish adding 127.0.0.1

varnish version 3.0.0
here is default.vcl

> backend default {
>       .host = "204.29.58.4";
>       .port = "80"; } sub vcl_recv {
>           if (req.http.Range) {
>                   return(pipe);
>           } }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `vcl_recv` function (which is appended to yours) contains this:

```
 if (req.restarts == 0) {
   if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
           req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
   } else {
       set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
   }
 }
```

..which is modifying the header.  To prevent this from happening, you should have your `vcl_recv` implemented as a full function that always returns, instead of depending on the appending of the default behavior, which contains config that you don't want.  Something like this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Range) {
      return(pipe);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" &&
      req.request != "HEAD" &&
      req.request != "PUT" &&
      req.request != "POST" &&
      req.request != "TRACE" &&
      req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.request != "DELETE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    return (lookup);
}
```